What is the best way to sound dampen a room?
My bedroom is located right next to my heat pump and it makes quite an annoying sound. I would like to sound dampen it. The room is obviously already drywalled and finished.
My plan:
Nail some sound dampener like this or staple some cork like this to the studs/ existing drywall, and nail new drywall over it.
My concern is that by doing this I am introducing a lot of new metal nails/staples, and I have read that the metal stuff is what carries the sound, so I am afraid that by doing all this I won't change a thing, or, even worse, make it louder.
My questions:

Which is better, cork or an cellulose sound panel? Or both?
Will the metallic nails/staples increase sound. Do you think I can glue either the cork or the panel to the drywall?
Is there a better way to accomplish what I want?



change the use of the room.


What type of heat pump? If it's an air heat pump and it's mounted on the wall, maybe you could use rubber mounts so it doesn't vibrate the wall, or mount it on the ground instead. All much simpler solutions than soundproofing a room...

@bobflux It's mounted on the ground, but the sound it gives off is so annoying. Replacing it would be way more expensive than the ideas I had, what do you think?

There are many past questions with the sound-prooifing tag. I recommend reviewing them. Basically, you want to add mass to the wall and/or decouple the wall surfaces from each other, depending on what frequencies you are trying to block. The outside unit could be relocated to be outside another room, though that would involve draining it of coolant and running new pipes and electrical to the new location, definitely a job for a pro in my opinion.

Resilient channel is one way to remove the direct connection between layers, and will be found in those other answers, or if you search on that term. The TL:DR on noise reduction - if it's high-pitched it's easy to stop noise, if it's low pitched it's hard (ranging to impossible, unless done at build time) to stop. If you have somewhere to put it and the line length constraints allow it, relocating the outside unit is your best bet.

To soundproof a wall, you need to add one layer of soft material that acts like a loose spring, then one layer of heavy material like drywall.
The idea is that the loose spring layer is not good at transmitting vibrations from the existing wall to the newly applied layer of drywall.
The ultimate way to soundproof a room is to make a box inside the room with its own structure (studs etc) and fill the space between it and the existing walls with sound absorbent material like rockwool. This is obviously a ton of work, wastes a lot of space, and does not solve the problem of doors and windows.
A simple and thin way to add some soundproofing to a wall is to glue a layer of loose felt to the wall, then glue a layer of drywall on top of it. This has less attenuation, but it only takes 25mm thickness or so.
Any treatment that does not include these two layers will not work. Cork is very light, so it will transmit vibrations from the wall into the air.
Controlling the noise at the source is often a better solution. For example if the heat pump is a bit far from the wall, you can build a small wall outside with heavy material like brick, just behind the heat pump, and roughly the size of the heat pump. This will act as a reflector and direct the noise away from the house.

Thank you for your detailed answer. Is there something that could work better than loose felt? I think that is what I will do.

You need a material that is soft yet strong enough to hold the drywall via gluing. So it needs good resistance to traction (ie, not fiberglass or soft rockwool). I use this felt, page is in French but you can look at the pic. It's an underlay that is normally used under carpet to absorb noise.

Thank you for your help! I will use something like that.
